# HTTPS Socket with request split in chunks

Tags: android, ssl, proxy

I have a question about how does HTTPS socket works.

I have to implement a bidirectional communication between a mobile device and a server.

I am getting the request, as raw bytes, from a bluetooth device, but the request is received in chunks and it waits for the response in the same way. I mean: the device is sending me a chunk, I have to send it to the server, and I have to send the server response back to device, to receive the 2nd chunk.

Well that works once, I mean I am opening the socket, I'm writing the request chunk, I'm reading the response chunk, but when I'm writing the 2nd request chunk, no data is received from the socket.

The code looks like:

```
if (webSocket == null) {
    SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    webSocket = factory.createSocket(DataUtils.stringValueFromByteArray(requestPackage.getHostAddress()),
                                                   DataUtils.intValueFromByteArray(requestPackage.getHostPort()));

}
 webInputStream = webSocket.getInputStream();
 webOutputStream = webSocket.getOutputStream();


 webOutputStream.write(requestPackage.getDataContent(), 0,requestPackage.getDataContent().length);
 webOutputStream.flush();

byte[] byteBuffer = getBytesFromInputStream(webInputStream);
```

Where getBytesFromInputStream looks like:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {



    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
    int ret = 0;
    while ((ret = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        bout.write(buf, 0, ret);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bout.toByteArray();
    return bytes;
}
```

The `webSocket` gets a `null` value when the request starts, and the connection should not end.

Now the problem is that this code is working for the first chunk, but on the second chunk of data, the `getButesFromInputStream` returns an empty array, because the `is.read()` returns -1 instantly.

Can anybody suggest what should I do, or maybe explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks,
Arkde

Comment: you probably need to wait a little time for the data to have the time to reach you. may be you can detect the -1 with a while loop and a small wait

Comment: This is up to your server, and presumably only you know how it works. Also, if you are indeed using HTTPS, don't use a raw socket but `HttpsURLConnection` or a similar HTTP client that understands the protocol.

Comment: @njzk2 The server is not mine, I'm trying to call any page that supports https.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov I am not implementing the server, but I'm requesting to each https supported server. I will try to implement this with httpsURLConnection and come with a response. Can you post your solution as an answer, so I can accept it if it works? Thanks

Comment: I have added an answer, but before trying things you might want to ask them what the expected protocol is.

Comment: i'm not saying that. all i'm saying is : you write data. immediately after that you check the content of the inputstream. It makes sense that it is empty. you need to wait a bit for the data to reach you. I suggest you wait while read is -1, then read until it is -1 again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed using HTTPS, don't use a raw socket but `HttpsURLConnection` or a similar HTTP client that understands the protocol. Then each next chunk from BT will sent as a new request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common misconception with TCP that the receiving application will get fragments of data in the same chunks as the way they've been sent by the sending application. All that TCP guarantees is the order (and eventual delivery, provided there's no error): this should be treated as a stream overall.

For this reason:

- reading 0 bytes is not an indication that the socket is closed (a common misconception too)
- application protocols must define delimiters or alternative ways to tell the other side when to stop reading, so as to be able to process the various commands of the application protocol.

HTTP 1.1 uses the `Content-Length` header to tell how many bytes must be read in the body of the request/response or [Chunked Transfer-Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), when the size isn't known when the header is sent.

If you want to read HTTP requests/responses, you'll need to process that: the header is terminated with a blank line, the length of the body is given by the `Content-Length` or by the various chunks you get.

Implementing this yourself is relatively straightforward if you want to read the content length, but it's certainly a bit more work if you also want to be able to process chunked transfer encoding. Overall, you might as well use an HTTP library, it will do it all for you. As Nikolay says, `HttpsURLConnection` is a good way. If this doesn't suit your needs, you can use the Apache Http Client library (also provided with Android AFAIK).

Comment: you may have noticed that this is not about http, but rather about sockets.

Comment: @njzk2, I have, but the question does ask about HTTPS. If you want to use your own protocol over plain sockets, you still need to define your own mechanism *within* that protocol to tell the recipient where the messages start and stop. Some protocols do this with some length header, others to this with line by line delimiters (e.g. SMTP/POP3 with `.` to end a message). You just need something.

Comment: yes, but no. it asks about https because it asks about websockets, which are usually viewed as an upgrade from http (literally they are, as the server answer to the handshake is "Upgrade: websocket"). far as i understand, after the upgrade, the websocket is basically a plain socket

Comment: @njzk2, not sure it's an actual "websocket" (only the variable name it seems, since it's client code), but if it is, it could be treated as a plain socket indeed, in which case the data sent over it still needs to be treated as a stream, not as chunks. You can only split the messages by using some sort of delimiter, not be how much is available or how much you read every time from the buffer.

Comment: he uses a `SSLSocketFactory`, so i would guess he uses sockets. (in which case delimiters are missing indeed)

Comment: @njzk2, indeed, but it's about HTTP over these `SSLSocket`s, in which case the delimiters are those of HTTP: content-length or chunked encoding. It's just not fun to deal with them yourself (especially the latter), so using an existing library sounds better. They have to be handled one way or another (since hoping for available/read to return the right thing at the right time isn't how it's meant to be done, and will only work by chance).

Comment: I have tried using the HTTClient, but it seems that when I'm trying to retrieve an output stream out of it, a IOException is thrown. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

in `getBytesFromInputStream`, before your while, add another while :

```
while (is.available() == -1) {
    Thread.sleep(100); // for instance. less may very well work too.
}
```

This will wait for some data to be available to read. (the time for the data to reach the server, the server to reply, and the data to reach you.)

### edit

for some reason is.available() seems to return 0, you can use is.read instead :

```
while (ret = (is.read(buf)) <= 0) {
    Thread.sleep(100); // for instance. less may very well work too.
}
bout.write(buf, 0, ret);
```

(the extra write avoids loosing the actually read data.)

The idea is to wait until some answer is received from the server, then actually read it.

Comment: is.available() returns 0 all the time, so the loop won't work.

Comment: Stopping to read based on how much is left in the buffer only works at best by coincidence (when it works, that is). That's just not the way to handle TCP connections at all.

Comment: reading until -1 does not read until nothing is left in the buffer, but rather until the end of stream signal has been received.

Comment: Most protocols exchange multiple requests/responses over the same TCP connection: you need something to tell the other side when they start and stop, and to tell the other side what to expect. Reading 0 or -1 is just not the way to do it.

Comment: did you test is.available() and does it always return 0?

Comment: -1 is not /read/, it is the way the java inputStream tells you it has received an end of stream

Comment: however, i agree that there should be some protocol defined length transmission at some point